# Adding graphic to sub JPANEL and Buttons to other

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jbutton

i have a code that needs buttons and text fields  to show above graphics but dont understand JPANELS at the moment the graphic hides theese options later i will be using a if statement that will take the season and draw image acordingly

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Weather extends JApplet implements ActionListener
    {

    JButton Enter , Exit;
    JTextField location;
    JLabel city;
    JRadioButton time;
    JComboBox Seasons;

      Random rand = new Random();
      int P = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;//Random Precipitation
       int  H = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;//Random Heat



    public void init ()
    {
             getContentPane() .setLayout (new FlowLayout ());

        Enter =new JButton ("Enter");
        Exit =new JButton ("exit");



        city = new JLabel ("What city?");
        location = new JTextField (20); //location entry field


        Seasons  = new JComboBox ();
        Seasons.addItem ("Summer");
        Seasons.addItem ("Fall");
        Seasons.addItem ("Winter");
        Seasons.addItem ("Spring");


        time = new JRadioButton ("check if night?");


       getContentPane().add (city);
       getContentPane().add (location);
       getContentPane().add (Seasons);
       getContentPane().add (time);

   }
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    { super.paintComponent(g);
       painter.paint(g);
    //Precipitation Bar
    g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (40, 170, 100, 20);//outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.blue);
        g.fillRect (40+1, 170+4, P, 14 ); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)

        //Temparature Bar
    g.setColor (Color.red);
        g.fillRect (170+4 ,50,14,100);//Covers in
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (170, 50, 20, 100);//outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.white);
        g.fillRect (170 +4, 50+1, 16, 100 - H); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)


        }


    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
    {

        }
}
```

Comment: 1) What does your `painter` variable represent? i.e., `painter.paint(g);`. 2) Does this code compile? 3) You will want to create a class that extends JPanel and do your drawing in that, not directly in the JApplet as you're trying to do. 4) Please have a look at the tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), for more suggestions on how to do Swing Graphics well.

Comment: Ok ill try that im limited on what i know how todo though and limited on time

Comment: K i tried that but Ready java wont run it for whatever reason wont even run there examples

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to help. If you are having problems with your code, you will want to: 1) post your latest code attempt, 2) post any complete error messages or exceptions that you might be seeing. 3) tell us any important details on your problem. Are you not able to run anything? What are you using to run your program with (Ready? -- I'm not sure what that is)?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Ready is a very basic program and Andrew you post this on alot of my stuff lol but i dont think they choose tis in there curriculum